# AlignParentBottom + marginBottom not working together

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-softkeyboard, window-soft-input-mode

In my activity's view I have `RelativeLayout` in which there are two layouts: LinearLayout-"**ll**" (must be top of the screen) and Relative one - "rl"(must be bottom of screen). When I'm focusing on editText in the **ll** it opens keyboard and my  **rl** ascends and shows on the **ll**. Then I try to use `android:layout_below="@+id/ll"` but it didn't worked. Also I tried to add `android:windowSoftInputMode=""` with various  parameters  in manifest but nothing helped.

**SO How to keep RelativeLayout "rl" bottom of the screen even when keyboard opens?**

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_container_padding"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:xxx="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

            <!-- Layout of username, password, Sign in button -->

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/llusernamePassLogin"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/loginPageText" />

                <am.bs.xxx.view.EditTextBase
                    android:id="@+id/login_vcardnumber"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/edit_text_margin"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="text" />

                <am.bs.xxx.view.EditTextBase
                    android:id="@+id/login_password"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/edit_text_margin"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/signin"
                    style="@style/main_button"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/edit_text_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/main_button_shape_selector"
                    android:onClick="createButtonClickListener"
                    android:text="@string/signIn" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- Create VCard or Register layout -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/llusernamePassLogin" >

                <!-- Register button -->
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/llRegisterButtonLayout"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/login_register_button"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/reg"
                        android:onClick="createButtonClickListener"
                        android:background="@color/transparent" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/registration" />    

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Create VCard button -->
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/llRegisterButtonLayout"
                    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                    <ImageButton 
                        android:id="@+id/create_vc_button"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/create_vcard"
                        android:onClick="createButtonClickListener"
                        android:background="@color/transparent" />

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/createVcard" />    

                </LinearLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you paste code of your layouts and AndroidManifest.xml? And you've tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, right?

Comment: Thanks for comment , Yes I tried , not helping

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and mark your root RelativeLayout as [isScrollContainer=true](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aisScrollContainer)

Comment: thanks for answer but it didn't helped. All problem is that my root Relative layout's height is fill_parent and second rl is alignParentBottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..   remove `android:layout_below="@+id/llusernamePassLogin"`

```
     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" >
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , but not helping :(